# A proper way to receive what is returned from a function called from a button, store it as another variable outside the function

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, tkinter-canvas

class Toplevel1:
    def cancel_login(self):
        msg = tk.messagebox.askyesno(title="Login Page", message="Are you sure you want to cancel Login")
        if msg:
            exit()

```
def login(self):
    name = self.txtUser.get()
    passwd = self.txtPasswd.get()
    if name and passwd:
        if name == "Samuel" and passwd == "Password191":
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Login Page", "Congratulations, Login was successful")
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Login Page", "Incorrect username or password")

        self.txtUser.select_clear and self.txtPasswd.select_clear()

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
    engine.setProperty('volume', 1.0)
    engine.setProperty('voice', "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0")
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def get_audio(self):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")

        audio = r.listen(source, 2)
        global said
        said = ""
        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            # said = r.recognize_sphinx(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

def __init__(self, top=None):
    '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
       top is the toplevel containing window.'''
    _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
    _compcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _ana1color = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _ana2color = '#ececec'  # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

    top.geometry("504x240+385+176")
    top.minsize(120, 1)
    top.maxsize(1268, 765)
    top.resizable(1, 1)
    top.title("Login Page")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

    self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
    self.Label1.place(relx=0.139, rely=0.208, height=24, width=79)
    self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.Label1.configure(text='''Username:''')

    self.Label2 = tk.Label(top)
    self.Label2.place(relx=0.119, rely=0.375, height=24, width=104)
    self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.Label2.configure(text='''Password:''')

    self.txtUser = tk.Entry(top)
    self.txtUser.place(relx=0.337, rely=0.208, height=20, relwidth=0.603)
    self.txtUser.configure(background="white")
    self.txtUser.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.txtUser.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
    self.txtUser.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.txtUser.configure(insertbackground="black")

    self.txtPasswd = tk.Entry(top)
    self.txtPasswd.place(relx=0.337, rely=0.375, height=20, relwidth=0.603)
    self.txtPasswd.configure(background="white")
    self.txtPasswd.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.txtPasswd.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
    self.txtPasswd.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.txtPasswd.configure(insertbackground="black")

    self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(top)
    self.btn_cancel.place(relx=0.337, rely=0.583, height=24, width=47)
    self.btn_cancel.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(pady="0")
    self.btn_cancel.configure(text='''Cancel''')
    self.btn_cancel.configure(command=self.cancel_login)

    self.btn_login = tk.Button(top)
    self.btn_login.place(relx=0.556, rely=0.583, height=24, width=41)
    self.btn_login.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
    self.btn_login.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
    self.btn_login.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.btn_login.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.btn_login.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.btn_login.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.btn_login.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.btn_login.configure(pady="0")
    self.btn_login.configure(text='''Login''')
    self.btn_login.configure(command=self.get_audio)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    vp_start_gui()

Don't worry about why I am calling the function from a login button but the main problem is that I cannot find a working way to save that "said" returned from the get_audio() function and store it as like text="the returned said word"

Any help or referrals would be deeply aprreciated. I have been stuck with this problem for days now, just can't seem to find a way out. I tried making said a global variable but it did not pass its value when i called it outside the function

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. I'm pretty sure that the colors are not critical to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your end goal is to display the text from `r.recognize_google(audio)` in for example a label widget.

I suppose what you could do is:

```
said = r.recognize_google(audio)
self.Label.configure(text=said)
```

Replace label with whatever widget you need to display the text on. Of course you have to check if the widget has a `text` parameter. For text widgets you need to use `.insert()`

What you're trying to do with global should work too, though. Maybe try removing `said = ""` from your code?

If, however you want to just get the text from the function for example use it in another function, you'd have to make `get_audio` return the text ( `return(said)` ) and then use that as a variable in what ever function you may need it in.

Something like

```
def get_audio(self):

      ...

            try:
                said = r.recognize_google(audio)
                return(said)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception: " + str(e))


def do_Something(self):
        said = self.get_audio()
        ...
```